# Flex PieSeries group by Label

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an array collection in Flex which looks like:-

```
public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        { Expense:"Taxes", Amount:2000 },
        { Expense:"Rent", Amount:1000 },
        { Expense:"Taxes", Amount:1000 },
        { Expense:"Food", Amount:1000 },
        { Expense:"Food", Amount:200 } ]);
```

Now the PieSeries has the dataprovider set to 'expenses' with field pointing to 'Amount' and labelField pointing to 'Expenses'. The problem here is that I get 5 pie slices instead of 3 (which is correct when we think that PieSeries will dump whatever exists in the dataProvider to UI).

Is there a way I can get Grouping around this data? Maybe by modifying the dataFunction and labelFunction?
What I expect is 3 slices showing up with value being the net sum - {Taxes:3000, Rent:1000, Food:1200} - similar to GROUP BY Label?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here: [How do I display grouped XML data in a Flex pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010110/how-do-i-display-grouped-xml-data-in-a-flex-pie-chart)

If that doesn't work out, I would preprocess the incoming data and create a new dataprovider with unique labels and the sum of the values. This will be a lot less complex that adding custom groupings and data functions.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your input. I did have a look at that question, but it made things overly complex.. I basically am looking at plotting the same data that exists for a datagrid shown right next to the pie chart. Pulling in the same data twice would be an overkill. Another inefficient way I could think of is to iterate through he whole dataset, counting the times a label exists. Anyway I could create a custom renderer or something similar so that the pie chart can group together all values having the same label?

Comment: I don't think iterating over the collection and creating a new dataprovider would be inefficient, but of course this depends on the size of the original collection. I would give it a try to be honest. A custom renderer will take you an another complex route.